# Interpreting the supremum

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, percentages

I came across this percentage problem in a high-school textbook:

> The marked price of a toy is $\$ 40$. What is the largest possible
>   discount per cent that can be given such that the selling price is not
>   less than $\$36 $?

And the solution given is:

> Let $x\%$ be the discount percent.
>   $$40(1-x\%) \geq 36$$
>   $$x\% \leq 10\%$$
>   $\therefore$ The largest possible discount per cent is $10\%$.

It is of course perfect. As a teacher, I start to think of what my students would answer. One possible answer I am interested in is this:

> Let $y\%$ be the **largest** discount percent.

If we still keep the inequality sign, i.e. $40(1-y\%) \geq 36$, what are we actually calculating? Are we considering the supremum of $y$? Is it even sensible to keep the inequality sign?

To rephrase my question, how should we interpret the answer, i.e. $y\% \leq 10\%$? I try to work on that but it is kind of difficult for me to give a clear explanation. Any help would be appreciated. If you think the question is not clear, please tell me so that I can amend it.

[ Please find my argument in the answer below. ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the maximum discount, let $y\%$, satisfies the following inequality:
$$y\%\geq x\%\text{, for every possible discount }x\%$$
Yet, since $y\%$ is still *a discount* as this is discussed in our problem, it should also satisfy the same restrictions as $x\%$ does, so, I feel that the inequality sign should remain.

One can see - of course not a student, but for extension purposes - the abovementioned problem as follows:

> Find the maximizing value of $x$ for the function:
>   $$f(x)=x$$
>   under the conditions:
>   $$\begin{align*}
> 40(1-x)-36&\geq0\\
> -x&\leq0\\
> x&\leq10
> \end{align*}$$

Under that phrasing, since the set of the restrictions is conmpact and $f$ is continuous, this problem has a solution and, the notion of supremum, due to compactness, coincides with that of maximum, so it is "well-hidden", Moreover, in this case the problem is made trivial, since the set of restrictions is a singleton; $\{10\}$.

So, back to the initial question, I think that there is no reason to drop the inequality sign since the maximum discount $y\%$ is, well, still a discount! :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have one question: Consider the inequality you mentioned at the beginning: $$ y\% \geq x\%$$ for every possible discount. It then implies $$40(1- x\%) \geq 40(1-y\%).$$ But it implies $40(1- x\%) \geq 40(1-y\%) = 36$. For if $40(1-y\%) \neq 36$, $y\%$ cannot be the largest possible discount. What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: In this case, it is assumed that the minimum value of $40(1-x\%)$ is exactly 36 which, in general, when looking for a minimum value is not always the case, that's why I wouldn't change the inequality sign to an equality sign. But, since we are talking about a teaching situation, it also depends on the class' level. In general, what is the mathematical idea behind this answer is that a function's maximum value over a set is not always attained at the boundary of the set.

Answer (score 1):

> If we still keep the inequality sign, i.e. $40(1-y\%) \geq 36$, what are we actually calculating?

Not calculating anything here. Just stating the premise of the problem: $\,y\,$ *is* a discount (doesn't matter at this point whether it's the largest or not), and so $\,y\,$ must satisfy the given ***in***equality.

> Is it even sensible to keep the inequality sign?

Not only sensible, but in fact *required*.

Imagine for example that you changed the problem to require "*the largest possible discount per cent **which is a multiple of 3%** that can be given such that the selling price is not less than $36$*". In that case the ***in***equality $\,y\% \le 10\%\,$ stays the same, but the actual answer will be $\,y\% = 9\%\,$.

> To rephrase my question, how should we interpret the answer, i.e. $y\% \leq 10\%$?

In plain English: the maximum discount $\,y\,$ cannot be larger than $\,10\%\,$.

Note that at this point $\,10\%\,$ is only an upper bound, not yet proved to be an actual maximum. It *happens* that $\,10\%\,$ is actually the answer ***in this case***, but that hasn't been established, yet.

> I try to work on that but it is kind of difficult for me to give a clear explanation.

The missing step, I think, is to recognize that, ***in this case***, *any* percent $\,0\% \le x\% \le 10\%\,$ qualifies as an eligible discount according to the stated rules. Therefore the *maximum* discount must be the largest amount all numbers in the range $\,[0\%, 10\%]\,$, and that number is $\,10\%\,$.

Answer (score 1):

The largest discount percentage that can be applied to a \$$40$ toy to ensure that the selling price is not less than \$$36$ is the discount price which will make the selling price exactly equal to \$$36$. If we call this discount percentage $y$ then we can drop the inequality sign and obtain the following equation:

$$40(1−y/100)=36$$

If we solve this equation we obtain $y=10$.

Now if we call $x$ a discount percentage that can be applied to a \$$40$ toy to ensure that the selling price is not less than \$$36$ then the equation above turns into an inequality, since there are an infinite number of possible answers:

$$40(1−x/100)≥36$$

If we solve this equation we obtain $x≤10$. In this case $y$ is simply the supremum of this infinite set:

$y=\text{sup}\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x≤10\}=10$

Therefore we have an equality for $y$, since $y$ can only take on a single value. Although $y$ also *satisfies* the inequality $y≤10$ that is not the same thing as being *defined* in terms of that inequality, in which case $y$ would have an infinite number of values, which is false. Furthermore, $y$  *satisfying* the inequality $y≤10$ provides us with less information about $y$ than the equality $y=10$, so there is no reason to keep the inequality.